# Override AutoFixture ICustomization registrations using moq / automoq and xunit

Tags: c#, .net, moq, xunit, autofixture

I have the following setup:

A calendar controller that calls a calendar service that calls a calendar client wrapper that calls the client. Controller -> Service -> ClientWrapper -> Client.

I am making an integration test that mocks the lowest tier (the client) and calls the controller to see if the client was called correctly.

My CalendarControllerBuilder:

```c#
internal class CalendarControllerBuilder
{
    public CalendarControllerBuilder()
    {
        CalendarClientMock = new Mock<ICalendarServiceClient>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    }

    public Mock<ICalendarServiceClient> CalendarClientMock { get; set; }

    public CalendarControllerBuilder With(Mock<ICalendarServiceClient> calendarClientWrapperMock)
    {
        CalendarClientMock = calendarClientWrapperMock;
        return this;
    }

    public CalendarController Create()
    {
        var calendarClientWrapperMock = new CalendarClientWrapper(CalendarClientMock.Object);
        
        var calenderService = new CalendarService(calendarClientWrapperMock);
        return new CalendarController(calenderService);
    }
}
```

Test setup with customization registration:

```c#
internal class CalenderControllerCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Register<CalendarController>(() =>
        {
            // ----- ICalendarServiceClient mock setups -----
            var calendarServiceClientMock = new Mock<ICalendarServiceClient>(MockBehavior.Strict);

            calendarServiceClientMock.Setup(m => m.GetEvents(It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
                                     .ReturnsAsync(fixture.Create<EventList>()).Verifiable();
            
            return new CalendarControllerBuilder()
                   .With(calendarServiceClientMock)
                   .Create();
        });
    }
}
```

My automoq data attribute (using AutoFixture.Xunit2):

```c#
public class Attributes
{
    public class AutoMoqDataAttribute<T> : AutoDataAttribute where T : ICustomization, new()
    {
        public AutoMoqDataAttribute()
            : base(() => new Fixture()
                       .Customize(
                                  new CompositeCustomization(
                                                             new AutoMoqCustomization(),
                                                             new T())))
        {
        }
    }

    public class AutoMoqDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
    {
        public AutoMoqDataAttribute()
            : base(() => new Fixture()
                       .Customize(
                                  new AutoMoqCustomization()))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

My test that works fine and uses the customization registration:

```c#
    [Theory]
    [AutoMoqData<CalenderControllerCustomization>]
    public async Task Test_GetAllEvents_ClientIsCalledCorrectlyAndReturnsCorrectData(
        IFixture fixture,
        [Frozen] Mock<ICalendarServiceClient> calendarServiceClientMock,
        CalendarController sut)
    {
        // Arrange
        var startDate = fixture.Create<DateTimeOffset>();
        var endDate = fixture.Create<DateTimeOffset>();

        // Act
        var eventList = await sut.GetAllEvents(startDate, endDate);

        // Assert
        eventList.Events.Count.Should().Be(3); // fixture always create 3 of lists here
        calendarServiceClientMock.Verify();
    }
```

THE PROBLEM:

Now I want to override the setup with my own data returned.

```c#
    [Theory]
    [AutoMoqData<CalenderControllerCustomization>]
    public async Task Test_GetAllEvents_ClientIsCalledCorrectlyAndReturnsCorrectData_Overridden(
        IFixture fixture,
        [Frozen] Mock<ICalendarServiceClient> calendarServiceClientMock,
        CalendarController sut)
    {
        // Arrange
        var startDate = fixture.Create<DateTimeOffset>();
        var endDate = fixture.Create<DateTimeOffset>();

        var result = fixture.Build<EventList>()
                            .With(x => x.Events, fixture.CreateMany<Event>(5).ToList())
                            .Create();

        // override client mock setup:
        calendarServiceClientMock.Setup(m => m.GetEvents(It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
                                 .ReturnsAsync(fixture.Build<EventList>()
                                                      .With(x => x.Events, fixture.CreateMany<Event>(5).ToList())
                                                      .Create()).Verifiable();

        // Act
        var eventList = await sut.GetAllEvents(startDate, endDate);

        // Assert
        eventList.Events.Count.Should().Be(5); // FAILS - IT GETS 3 AND NOT 5
        calendarServiceClientMock.Verify(); // THIS FAILS TOO IF I SET 3 IN ABOVE
    }
```

I have tried with and without the Frozen attribute.

What am I missing here? I don't want to call my calendarcontroller builder as the point is to avoid boilerplate. Do I need a registration of the client or something else I'm missing

(maybe related to [Override Autofixture customization setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49576741/override-autofixture-customization-setup) but using moq and not n-subtitute. Could not get this to work even with correct order of parameters)

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current way you customize the fixture I don't think you can. By creating a custom builder and instantiating the mock by hand you've basically painted yourself in a corner.

To get AutoFixture to control the instances you need in the test, you must allow it to generate them. Here's a possible solution.

The root of your SUT is the controller. Let's say it receives as a parameter an `ICalendarService` that's always the concrete implementation `CalendarService`.

To tell AutoFixture that the implementation is always a concrete type you can relay the resolved type to the concrete implementation.

```cs
fixture.Customizations.Add(new TypeRelay(typeof(ICalendarService), typeof(CalendarService)));
```

Next the service takes as a constructor parameter an abstraction that's `ICalendarClient` which is resolved as the wrapper but only for the service. This means you have to identify the constructor parameter and relay the request to the wrapper type.

```cs
fixture.Customizations.Add(new FilteringSpecimenBuilder(
    new FixedRequestRelay(typeof(CalendarClientWrapper)),
    new YourConstructorParameterSpecification()));
```

The `YourConstructorParameterSpecification` is a `IRequestSpecification` implementation that identifies a request as a parameter of type `ICalendarClient` that belongs to the constructor of type `CalendarService`.

`FixedRequestRelay` is a simple `ISpecimenBuilder` that always resolves the same predefined request from `ISpecimenContext` instead of the received one.
Here's a very basic implementation of it.

```cs
public record FixedRequestRelay(object Request) : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
        => context.Resolve(this.Request);
}
```

Next you have your wrapper that also takes as a parameter an abstraction of type `ICustomerClient`. However this instance you want to be resolved as a mock that you can control from the test. Since you use AutoFixure.AutoMoq you can leave this one as is and let AutoMoq generate a mock for it.

Let's say this is the resulting customization.

```cs
public class CalendarCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customizations.Add(new TypeRelay(typeof(ICalendarService), typeof(CalendarService)));
        fixture.Customizations.Add(new FilteringSpecimenBuilder(
            new FixedRequestRelay(typeof(CalendarClientWrapper)),
            new AndRequestSpecification(
                new ParameterSpecification(typeof(ICalendarClient), "client"),
                new ParameterMemberSpecification(
                    new DeclaringTypeSpecification(
                        new ExactTypeSpecification(typeof(CalendarService)))))));
    }
}
```

By using it you can write a test like this.

```cs
[Theory, MyData]
public async Task Foo(
    [MinLength(5)] Event[] events,
    [Frozen] Mock<ICalendarClient> clientMock,
    CalendarController controller,
    DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    clientMock
        .Setup(x => x.GetAllEvents(It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(events);

    var actual = await controller.GetAllEvents(start, end, default);

    Assert.Equal(events, actual);
}
```